# Slick: Option column filtering

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I want to do something like this (this is a made-up example to simplify my actual problem):

```
def findByGender(isMale: Option[Boolean]) = {
  People.filter(row => row.name.isNotNull && isMale match {
    case Some(true) => row.wife.isNotNull      // find rows where wife column is not null
    case Some(false) => row.wife.isNull        // find rows where wife column is null
    case None => true                          // select everything
  })    
}
```

This does not compile because of the last "true". Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make it a `Column[Boolean]`:

```
def findByGender(isMale: Option[Boolean]) = {
  People.filter(row => row.name.isNotNull && isMale match {
    case Some(true) => row.wife.isNotNull      // find rows where wife column is not null
    case Some(false) => row.wife.isNull        // find rows where wife column is null
    case None => LiteralColumn(true)           // select everything
  })    
}
```

Comment: How did you find this? I can't even find any mention of `LiteralColumn` [here](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/search.html?q=LiteralColumn&check_keywords=yes&area=default)

Comment: No idea where I found it. Was a very long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Slick 3.3.x you can use the following solution:

```
def findByGender(isMale: Option[Boolean]) = 
  People
    .filter(_.name.isDefined)
    .filterIf(isMale == Some(true))(_.wife.isDefined)
    .filterIf(isMale == Some(false))(_.wife.isEmpty)
```

or

```
def findByGender(isMale: Option[Boolean]) = 
  People
    .filter(_.name.isDefined)
    .filterOpt(isMale) {
      case (row, true) => row.wife.isDefined
      case (row, false) => row.wife.isEmpty
    }
```

There are 3 cases:

1. `isMale` is defined and equal `Some(true)`

   Result SQL: `select * from people when (name is not null) and (wife is not null);`
2. `isMale` is defined and equal `Some(false)`:

   Result SQL: `select * from people when (name is not null) and (wife is null);`
3. `isMale` is empty

   Result SQL: `select * from people when name is not null;`