# Filtering on an option of a custom column in Slick 3.0.2

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I am having some issues getting the following example to compile.

```
import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._

case class Age(value: Int)
case class User(id: Long, age: Option[Age])

object Dao {
  implicit val ageColumnType: TypedType[Age] = MappedColumnType.base[Age, Int](_.value, Age(_))

  class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {
    def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def age = column[Option[Age]]("age")
    def * = (id, age) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
  }

  val users = TableQuery[UserTable]
  def byId(id: Long)(implicit session: Session): Option[User] = {
    users.filter(_.age === Some(Age(21))).firstOption
  }
}
```

But the compiler is failing with the following error:

```
Example.scala:16:28: value === is not a member of slick.lifted.Rep[Option[Age]]
```

Does the right way to do this involve using `OptionColumnExtensionMethods` or something? It is strange that the type-classes for `TypedType[Option[T]]` would not kick in here, however.

---

Here is a list of some other resources I dug up, but none of them seem to deal with a container type around a custom column type using `mappedColumnType`.

- [Filtering when using custom column type in Slick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483811/filtering-when-using-custom-column-type-in-slick)
- [Slick: Option column filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26554224/slick-option-column-filtering)
- [Slick and filtering by Option columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554304/slick-and-filtering-by-option-columns)

Comment: did you try with ==?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out and figured it was worth posting here.

---

The following line had too broad of a type signature.

```
implicit val ageColumnType: TypedType[Age]
```

Obviously, the implicit scope no longer contained the right evidence to infer the various column operators needed in the `filter` query, including the `===` method. Instead, I just needed a more specific type:

```
implicit val ageColumnType: BaseColumnType[Age]
```

---

As per the comment on the original question, the `==?` solution also works once this change is made. Thanks!